WHERE IS MY MONEY?
okay so i started mining for ether using ai on remix and i left it for a while and now my money is gone and it says no money is in my account on etherscan.io and none in remix, plus no money in metamask which ive been using. I have no idea where my money is and im freaking out because its dissapeared, it doesnt even show when it starts to mine. Did remix steal my money?? also it says internal transactions, it says that i made one a 2 hours ago with all of my ether to some guy but i didn't authorize that at all so what now?? like where is my money and what do i do?

Please give your address at least. And list what did you do (step by step) on remix? So people can understand and explain what happened with your money.

Mining on Ethereum is no longer possible after the switch to Proof-of-Stake. It is very likely you were scammed to send the money to a contract that does not mine, and send your funds to the scammer.
